# Update web.config in Web Farms

Tags: asp.net, web-config, web-farm

I'm writing an ASP.Net Web Application that can be deployed to Web Farms. I've written some code to update a few config options (AD Membership server, Selected Theme, etc), but now i'm wondering how can they be synchronized between multiple servers? It looks like sharepoint has a feature to manage those scenarios, but i have no clue how to do it without using powershell scripts or putting those settings in a shared folder. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some relatively new bits from Microsoft out to help with this called the IIS Web Deployment Tool.

http://www.iis.net/extensions/WebDeploymentTool